# How to overwrite a SharePoint document using CopyIntoItems api of Copy.asmx

Tags: ios, sharepoint

I need to save a file from iPhone/iPad to SharePoint site. When I tried to upload content with the same name of one document that actually there, it succeeds and even file size is shown as that of the new one. But content remains as the initial file as itself.

Do anyone have a solution for this?. Please let me know if something is there.

Comment: Do you have public and draft versioning on the list?

Comment: What does that mean? I have a normal document library and I am trying to uploading to that.

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled? Is checkin required for content approval?

Comment: No I think. But I tried in that way also. I checked out the document using "CheckOutFile" api of Lists.asmx, uploaded/overwrite the file using "CopyIntoItems" of Copy.asmx and then checked in using "CheckInFile" of Lists.asmx. Still the content in SharePoint site remains the same as what it was, all the metadata are reflected even the size of the content. Any idea why does this happen?